# Representations of general linear group

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, representation-theory

It is known that some of the irreducible representations of general linear group are related to irreducible representations of symmetric group. Due to this relation we can index irreducible representations of general linear group by integer partition. My question is that given an integer partition $\lambda=(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)$ how do I find irreducible representation of $GL(V)$ related to this partition?

Comment: The irreducible representations are given by Schur functors $S_\lambda(V)=V^{\otimes n}\otimes_{\Bbb C[S_n]}M_\lambda$ where $M_\lambda$ is an irreducible representation of $S_n$ associated to $\lambda$ (explicitly, a Specht module).

Comment: Are you familiar with highest weight theory for $GL(V)$? It is fairly easy to translate from that language to the language of partitions, but I'd like to know what your background is before I give an answer.

Comment: @David Hill, No i do not know about highest weight. I know basic representation theory, young tableaux etc and schur-weyl duality.

Comment: @DavidHill Can you give that answer translating from highest weights to partitions?